# TypeScript Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In this fragment I Have the next error :

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322
```

```
export async function GetCertainCoinByType(coinId: string) {
  const response = await axios.get(URLofCertainCoins + `certain/${coinId}`, {
      headers : {
          token : localStorage.getItem('token'),
      }
  });
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Localestorage getItem can potentially return null so you need to check for this..  I personally would throw an exception, as calling this fn without a token would seem invalid.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the return type of [Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is `string | null`, and not just `string`. To avoid this exception, you can first get the item from local storage and then use it like:

```js
export async function GetCertainCoinByType(coinId: string) {
  let tokenFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if (!tokenFromStorage ) { 
    throw new Error("no token supplied"); 
  }
  const response = await axios.get(URLofCertainCoins + `certain/${coinId}`, 
  {
      headers : {
          token : tokenFromStorage 
      }
  });
  return response;
}
```

Comment: It's nearly there, you forgot to put the bounds check in.  eg.  on the next line after the `let`, just put something like -> `if (tokenFromStorage === null) { throw new Error("no token supplied"); }`  or something like that.  This will then make TS happy.

Comment: I tried to point out the use of avoiding the error, as there will be token present in OP's perspective. But that's not true, agreed. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out @CollinD and Keith

Comment: Unfortunately your update of calling `getItem` will cause the error again.. :(   Using your original let, and doing the check after the let will fix that.  That because getItem will always return `string | null`, but after doing a bounds check on the `let` it will become `string`..

Comment: Not sure why I am in a hurry, just did that

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether `token` is null, and if it is, exit the function.

Now `response` is a Promise anyway, since it's returned by an `async` function. You don't need to `await` Axios, then re-convert it to a Promise afterwards. You can directly `return axios.get(...)` and since this removes the only `await`, it turns out you don't even need the `async/await` syntax at all here.

```
export function GetCertainCoinByType(coinId: string): Promise<any> {

  const token:string|null = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if(!token){
    console.log("No token!");
    return ;
  }

  return axios.get(URLofCertainCoins + `certain/${coinId}`, {
      headers : { token }
  });
}
```

Comment: There really is no reason to put `token:string|null`,  implicit type is fine here.  It's the bounds check that's important..

Comment: My goal is to be explicit for the sake of demonstration and for the answer to be clear :)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense..  Just wanted to make sure other's reading this don't assume been explicit here is what's fixing the issue, rather than the bounds check..